# Translate3d parent covers position: absolute child

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to add a new element to a list where the list items are all positioned using `translate3d`. The thing I am attempting to add is a dropdown menu that I'm styling with `position: absolute` but the parent elements are all laying on top because of the `translate3d`. Can this be fixed? z-index seems to have zero impact.

Here is a fiddle showing the basic positioning problem:
<s>http://jsfiddle.net/etb4f0x4/</s>

Assuming I can't touch the styling of the `.list` items can I fix the `.dropdown` items?

edit: new fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/w8ra5qbe/

Comment: it looks like adding `position: absolute` to your `row` class solves the z-index issue... but I'm not sure if that's result you're looking for. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bonez0607/3sm6w4xt/)

Comment: are you trying to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/etb4f0x4/1/

Comment: @JoeB. that solution works perfectly for the fiddle I gave you. Unfortunately I'm a moron and made an error in the markup in the fiddle since it didn't match the real project I'm working on. Anyway upvote for you but if you have any ideas here is a corrected fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/w8ra5qbe/

Comment: I see now... and you mentioned you are unable to touch the list items, correct? (ie `.item1, .item2,` and `.item3`). Without being able to touch the list items I'm not sure you can achieve what you're attempting. Otherwise you could try something like this [https://jsfiddle.net/bonez0607/rvkpub27/](https://jsfiddle.net/bonez0607/rvkpub27/). However, rows 1 and 2 will overlay menu 3, if you use `position: absolute` on `.row` class. The other option could be to use some javascript.

Comment: Yeah I can't touch the .item classes since they're outside of the component I'm trying to add. Might be time to look at a JS solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css rule called `.row span` and add the following to it. To get at the root of your question, you need to add a `position` property to the rules you want to add `z-index` to. These elements have a default of `position: static` which ignores `z-index`.

```
.row span {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bonez0607/yL9kg573/)

Comment: I removed `position: absolute` from the `.row` rule, but that can be added back in if you need the yellows to appear more like the first I had posted.

Comment: That doesn't exactly seem to work. You can see the problem better if you put display: none on the middle dropdown. I need the first dropdown to show up on top of the 2nd row. Fiddle example with display:none like I mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/8xbx0Lwg/